# Access Changed on Google Cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I had a simple Google Cloud Storage Account (for the last 5 years) that I had a small online backup service offering for my clients.

About a month or so ago I began getting messages about my "Trial" was expiring ... I ignored it mostly since I had not setup a trial anything. Then about a couple of weeks ago, my backup service quite working with the message I had no cloud account.

I went back and found the emails and clicked and "Upgraded" the account (which again I have no idea why since I have been paying Google Cloud Storage for years) and the backup began to work again.

But now when I go to look at the Project it states I have no permission for anything. I had access until this garbage happened ... of course there is absolutely no way to get support from Google.

I have tried to see how to give me admin access again, but there does not seem to be any way to do this ...

BTW ... I am the only login

Help please

Comment: When did you create this account? When did the Free Trial expire? Do you have more than one account? Which account have you been paying for years? Without details on your account and the exact steps you have tried to solve this, we can only guess. Note: You can open a chat box with Google Cloud Billing Support for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

about a year ago, some requirements were changed with GCP and storage. as such, you will need to ensure you have an attached billing account and manager access on the accounts that you are using to back up with. Typically these are service accounts with service credentials.

You can find the IAM roles here: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam
you will have to ensure you are in the correct project, then select the user that you are using to authorize with the backup service (or potentially create one).

Then you will want to edit the roles this account has with any of the following, or their subset permissions:

- Storage Admin
- Storage Transfer
- Storage Object Admin

I also highly recommend getting a Google/Firebase technician to look at your GCP project, you can contact them through support here as they can debug if there are any backend issues. Just clarify that your project may not be a Firebase project. They are often more helpful than typical Google Support.

- https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

**Update:**
If for some reason your account was hijacked or migrated to an account you don't have access to when you should. contacting GCP support is your best option, they are able to restore access, roll back changes, and otherwise assist with any potential lockouts you have.

Comment: Wow ... thank you for the information !

I hardly have to login to the Storage Account ... I did not know the "rules" changed ...

The only issue I have now is that when I log in, I see the project listed fine, but basically I have no permission to do anything ... I getthe message that I do not have permission to do this ... I can't see anything in IAM, or can I actually open my project ...

I will contact the Billing to see if there is something there ... and look at the firebase support ... I don't think it is firebase ... my 3rd party backup program just uses storage buckets ...

Comment: that is suspicious, It's almost like your account was hijacked. I hope it get's resolved soon! GCP support can be slow but without account access from us or yourself, our hands are currently tied.

Comment: I called the GCP Support and ultimately she told me that I was not listed as the owner, but she was sending a message to the listed owner ...
I am not sure how but the owner got changed to a gmail email that I do not use and I was able to add my correct email as an owner and then get access ....

What is strange is that that email listed as owner, I have never used or do I even access gmail with ... I would have never changed or used it for anything ... 

What a day ...

Comment: Are you in control or know this other email account? Is it possible the password or endpoint was compromised? I'm glad you have answers but the issue is what to do if the new account holder doesn't respond, or is abandoned.

Comment: That email I had used to set up a better SMTP Server for my emails about a year ago... I was having issues with my emails reaching my clients with gmail accounts ... I got tired of sending the video out how to whitelist my email/domain. Even some that had done this process, gmail would randomly block my emails.

I had already went through all the SPF steps, and thought maybe if i use gmail as an SMTP, it would improve ... I never got it to work and never used this email ... I have no idea how this got listed as an owner... I have added my correct email as owner, and removed the gmail one ...

Comment: Glad you found a solution! if you found my answer helpful, it would help me if you could accept it.